# Using the Apple Music API to create playlist?

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm working on an `iOS app(swift)` that provides a faster way for users to create playlists from their `Apple Music library`. After reading the documentation I still can't figure out how to get acces to the users library.

Is there a way I can get accesss to all the songs in the users library and add the song ids to an `array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access Apple's music library, you will need to add the "Privacy - Media Library Usage Description" to your info.plist. Then you need to make your class conform to MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate. To display the Apple Music library, you present the MPMediaPickerController. To add the songs to an array, you implement the didPickMediaItems method of MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate.

```
    class MusicPicker:UIViewController, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {
    //the songs the user will select
    var selectedSongs: [URL]!

    //this method is to display the music library.
    func getSongs() {

    var mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController?

    mediaPicker = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: .music)

    mediaPicker?.delegate = self

    mediaPicker?.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true

    mediaPicker?.showsCloudItems = false
    //present the music library
    present(mediaPicker!, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

//this is called when the user selects songs from the library
func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
   //these are the songs that were selected. We are looping over the choices
   for mpMediaItem in mediaItemCollection.items {
     //the song url, add it to an array
    let songUrl = mpMediaItem.assetURL
    selectedSongs.append(songURL)
   }
   //dismiss the Apple Music Library after the user has selected their songs
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
   //if the user clicks done or cancel, dismiss the Apple Music library
   func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {

          dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Why do set showsCloudItems to false? I would like to use icloud songs as well for access is it as simple as changing this to true?

Comment: Yes you could set it true. I just made it false in my example.

Comment: Can I put all the user's song in an array without presenting the library?

Comment: MPMediaPickerController is meant for users to pick the songs they want with a presented library. There is another API called MPMediaLibrary that could do something like that but as far as I know it is read-only for iOS devices. I'd encourage you to look at that.